# How to keep waiting Backbone model.save for data from asynchronous getGeolocation() function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, backbone.js

I have a function `getLocation()` which gets geolocation by using HTML5.

```js
var environmentInfo = {
  OS: OSName,
  browser: browserName,
  browserVersion: fullVersion
};

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, showError);
  } else {
    environmentInfo.geoServiceNotSupported = true;
  }
}

function successCallback(position) {
  environmentInfo.geoServiceRefused = false;
  environmentInfo.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  environmentInfo.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      environmentInfo.geoServiceRefused = true;
      break;
  }
}


this.activity = this.transaction.save({
        envData: {
          "Environment-GeoService-Refused-By-User": this.environmentInfo.geoServiceRefused,
          "Environment-GeoService-Not-Supported": this.environmentInfo.geoServiceNotSupported,
          "Meta-Geolocation-Lat": this.environmentInfo.latitude,
          "Meta-Geolocation-Long": this.environmentInfo.longitude
        }
      },
      {
        success: this.onStartTransaction,
        error: this.onStartTransactionError
      });
```

And also I have a Backbone.Model which stores and save some data including geolocation.
But I need a logic which will be waiting for geolocation in the model and only then - save to backend.

Comment: Why not just call `model.save()` in geolocations success callback after setting data..?

Answer (score 0):

Move `this.activity = this.transaction.save()` inside your "success callback" for the geolocalisation.

Comment: Can you explain what's the use of assigning the jqXhr to `this.activity`? How are you going to use it..?

Comment: I have no idea. He does it in his, I assumed he has a reason, so I kept it that way for him.

Comment: If that is the case, please use comments to get more information from the OP first to post a useful answer. If you take a closer look, there is already a comment asking why op can't save the model inside success callback posted long before your answer which doesn't include any further information.

Comment: I don't really need more information for my answer to be valid though. Moving to the success callback will do what OP wants, so I told him that.

While you are right that the content is pretty much the same as your comment, it doesn't make it less correct and is not warrant of your downvote.

Comment: *"Moving to the success callback will do what OP wants"*- No. where is `this.environmentInfo.latitude` being set..? What do you think `this` will refer to in success callback..?